# How to add multiple attachments using Amazon SES email?

Tags: bash, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES to send an email in a bash script.

I am able to add a single attachment, but I'm not sure how to add multiple.

How I am constructing the email:

```
echo '{"Data": "From: '${SENDER}'\nTo: '${RECIPIENT}'\nSubject: '${SUBJECT}'\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n'${BODY}'\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: text/plain;\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"attachment.txt\"\n\nThis is the text in the attachment.\n\n--NextPart--"
}' > "$tmp_message"
```

Comment: Doing this via bash is obviously not fun, you should really try and user higher level languages like Java and python, especially for more complicated tasks like sending emails. What is the code you currently have? In what way does it fail sending multiple attachments?

Comment: @luk2302 this is how I am constructing the email that is then sent:  echo '{"Data": "From: '${SENDER}'\nTo: '${RECIPIENT}'\nSubject: '${SUBJECT}'\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n'${BODY}'\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: text/plain;\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"attachment.txt\"\n\nThis is the text in the attachment.\n\n--NextPart--"
}' > "$tmp_message"